# Override Materialize CSS properties

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have included **first** Materialize's CSS and **then** I have linked my css file.

In which I have an example class that sets `background-color` property to `red`, but that doesn't override the default color (that's set by materialize-css).

Here's an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/79ss2eyr/1/

I'd like not to change anything in materialize's source files, instead I want to add additional classes and set my additional colors.

Here's what the inspector says:

[image]

How should I do that and why my css properties do not override materialize's since it's linked **after** the framework?

Comment: i think you want the color of text to be red?

Comment: @GauravAggarwal sorry, have made a mistake in jsfiddle. Fixed it.

Comment: no problem...check my answer with you solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inn Materialize's the rule is set by `footer.page-footer {}`, but you're wrote just `.app-bg`. So you can't override the Materialize's  rule.

If u want to override that class you can use `footer.app-bg` or use `!important`:

```
footer.app-bg {
  background-color: red;
}
```

or

```
.app-bg {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: This is strange..you edited the complete answer of krishna and merged other answers in it??

Comment: @ Gaurav Aggarwal   ---  noo... your wrong  @Ivanka Todorova  just formatting my answer. not merged.

Comment: The use of !important should not be encouraged. It is a very bad practice.

Answer (score 7):

Make the css selector more specific, like this:

```
footer.app-bg {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your css is not applying to the element because of other applied css just use `!important` to specify that your css is important.

```
.app-bg {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/79ss2eyr/2/