# How to override materizlize.css modal-content

Tags: html, css, materialize

I saw [this stackoverlfow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792910/override-materialize-css-properties), but both options didn't work for me.

I'm using materialize.css and I have an image that uses the modal-content class. On the webpage when I inspect the element of the modal, I can add the command `top: 170px` to shift the modal down 170px.

[image]

However, I can't seem to get this to change on the backend.

Html Code I'm trying to adjust.

```
<div class="modal fade"  id="modalCrop">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
```

I've tried things like adding a new class

```
.test{
    top: 170px
}
```

or changing the current class, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
.modal-content{
    top: 170px !important;
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: How is `modal-content` defined in materialize.css? If it specifies more elements (like `thing.other-thing.modal-content`), do so as well. Also: your code should be below that of materialize. Look up "CSS specifity"

Comment: So I happen to have both boostrap.min.css and materialize.css installed and I think they are conflicting. I found everything listed in the above picture in the boostrap.min.css file. But either way, is there a way to replace just one parameter instead of having to find the .modal-content and all thing.other-thing.modal-content

Comment: Are you using a (third) custom css file as well? If so: in the html, inlcude your css file last (under bootstrap and materialize), and in that file try overriding

Comment: I know it's bad form, but on the html page below 'extends base.html' and above the block content I am including the <style>css</style> code. This is an easy way for me to test it and then when I get it right I'll put it where it belongs. So, yes I believe I have it last so it isn't overwritten.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: welll, thanks for trying to help. i'm in so deep i don' tkonw how to even do that. i'm going to try something else.